# Output returns null results when read from a file

Tags: c, file, structure

I am trying to make an information system but whenever I try and print the output, it only prints out the last thing I enter. Here is the function I am using.

```
void displayStudents(){
    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("studentlist.txt", "rb");
    if(!fp){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }else{

        studentInfo s;

        while(fread(&s, sizeof(studentInfo), 1, fp) && !feof(fp)){
            printf("Student Number: %i\n", s.studentNumber);
            printf("Last Name: %s\n", s.lastName);
            printf("First Name: %s\n", s.firstName);
            printf("Course: %s\n", s.course);
            printf("Year Level: %i\n", s.yearLevel);
            printf("Age: %i\n", s.age);
            printf("Sex: %c\n", s.sex);
            printf("Final Grade: %i\n", s.finalGrade);
            printf("\n\n");
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

}
```

Where `studentInfo` is a struct  containing the following...

```
struct studentInfo{
    int studentNumber;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[15];
    char course[15];
    int yearLevel;
    int age;
    char sex;
    int finalGrade;
};
typedef struct studentInfo studentInfo;
```

The output of the program is as follows:

```
Student Number: 0
Last Name:
First Name:
Course:
Year Level: 0
Age: 0
Sex:
Final Grade: 0


Student Number: 0
Last Name:
First Name:
Course:
Year Level: 0
Age: 0
Sex:
Final Grade: 0


Student Number: 3
Last Name: Rambo
First Name: Ra
Course: CS
Year Level: 1
Age: 10
Sex: F
Final Grade: 89
```

I tried *enrolling* 3 students but it only prints out information for the last and not the ones before. I want it to be able to display all student info I input.

Comment: The file extension `.txt` implies that your input file is a text file. However, the fact that you are using `fread` implies that your input file is binary, not text. Please show us the contents of your input file.

Comment: Oh I see, so I was using the wrong file type. Thank you! It works now~

Comment: `"File could not be opened.\n"` is the canonical example of a useless error message, and you are writing it to the wrong stream.  Try `const char *path = "studentlist.txt"; if( (fp = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL ){ perror(path);...`

Comment: The call to `feof` in the condition of the while loop is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was placing binary in the file and was only reading it as a `.txt` so it never worked out. Thats why I merely changed my file type to `.bin` from `.txt` that way it would read and it did. I was also reading a bin file normally like any other text when i should have done `rb`. My bad.

Comment: This explanation does not seem complete. Do you have several input files, one named `mystudents.txt` and one named `mystudents.bin`, and did you load the wrong input file? Or do you only have one input file, and did you just rename that file?

Comment: After your most recent edit, the answer still does not make sense to me. You claim that the problem was that you were reading the file as a text file, but the code in the question contains the line `fp = fopen("studentlist.txt", "rb");`, which opens the file in binary mode (due to the `b`). Also, the code in the question uses `fread`, which means it is being read as unformatted (non-text) data. Therefore, as far as I can tell, either your question or your answer contains false information, because they seem to contradict each other. The name of the file (`.txt` or `.bin`) should not matter.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not do any other changes than rename the file from `.txt` to `.bin`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i did not, it turns out i was writing in binary this whole time but i was reading it as normal text, that's why it did not work.

Comment: Oh yeah, ur explanation makes more sense. I am sorry, I am not very well-versed in these terminologies and I just started understanding this. Sadly, nobody gave a more comprehensive answer so I just placed what I did that made things work out for me in hope of hoping to help other people who might have encountered something similar.

Comment: If what you say is true, however, how come it worked fine when I used `.bin` instead of `.txt`?